# How to wrap a code block using an if statement, meaning is there a ruby way to do this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a block like this:

```
Blah.where(....).each do |b|
  # Code here
end
```

I only want to run this if `some_var` is not `nil` or empty. Is there a ruby way to do this other than:

```
if !some_var.nil
  Blah.where(....).each do |b|
    # Code here
  end
end
```

Comment: Your condition will be true when `some_var` is empty. I thought you didn't want that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you might want

```
unless some_var.nil?
```

instead.

ALSO you can use an `end if` at the end of the block

Answer (score 2):

```
Blah.where(....).each do |b|
  #...
end if some_var
```

Answer (score 2):

You could look into the [AndAnd](http://andand.rubyforge.org/) gem for some inspiration on solving problems with nil. For an overview [check out my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766191/ruby-nil-like-object/8766405#8766405).

Other then that the probably best way is to do

```
Blah.where(...).each do |a|
   ...
end unless some_var.nil?
```