# Easy way to parse hashes and arrays

Tags: ruby

Typically, parsing XML or JSON returns a hash, array, or combination of them. Often, parsing through an invalid array leads to all sorts of `TypeError`s, `NoMethodError`s, unexpected nils, and the like.

For example, I have a `response` object and want to find the following element:

```
response['cars'][0]['engine']['5L']
```

If response is

```
{ 'foo' => { 'bar' => [1, 2, 3] } }
```

it will throw a `NoMethodError` exception, when all I want is to see is `nil`.

Is there a simple way to look for an element without resorting to lots of nil checks, rescues, or Rails `try` methods?

Comment: Does `response['cars'][0]['engine']['5L'] rescue nil` count as "a lot of rescues" ?

Comment: I generally don't like catch-all inline rescues. http://devblog.avdi.org/2012/11/19/rubytapas-022-inline-rescue/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Ruby 2.3, the answer is [`dig`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to look through both the Hash documentation and also through [Facets](http://rubyworks.github.com/facets/index.html), but nothing stood out as far as I could see.

So you might want to implement your own solution. Here's one option:

```
class Hash
  def deep_index(*args)
    args.inject(self) { |e,arg|
      break nil if e[arg].nil?
      e[arg]
    }
  end
end

h1 = { 'cars' => [{'engine' => {'5L' => 'It worked'}}] }
h2 = { 'foo' => { 'bar' => [1, 2, 3] } }

p h1.deep_index('cars', 0, 'engine', '5L')
p h2.deep_index('cars', 0, 'engine', '5L')
p h2.deep_index('foo', 'bonk')
```

Output:

```
"It worked"
nil
nil
```

Comment: @peter I'm calling it `deep_index`, not fetch. Not sure what you mean?

Comment: sorry, was this error p h2.deep_index('foo', 'bar', 0, 'engine')  { nil } # `[]': can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)

Answer (score 1):

Casper was just before me, he used the same idea (don't know where i found it, is a time ago) but i believe my solution is more sturdy

```
module DeepFetch
  def deep_fetch(*keys, &fetch_default)
    throw_fetch_default = fetch_default && lambda {|key, coll|
      args = [key, coll]
      # only provide extra block args if requested
      args = args.slice(0, fetch_default.arity) if fetch_default.arity >= 0
      # If we need the default, we need to stop processing the loop immediately
      throw :df_value, fetch_default.call(*args)
    }
    catch(:df_value){
      keys.inject(self){|value,key|
        block = throw_fetch_default && lambda{|*args|
          # sneak the current collection in as an extra block arg
          args << value
          throw_fetch_default.call(*args)
        }
        value.fetch(key, &block) if value.class.method_defined? :fetch
      }
    }
  end

  # Overload [] to work with multiple keys
  def [](*keys)
    case keys.size
    when 1 then super
    else deep_fetch(*keys){|key, coll| coll[key]}
    end
  end

end

response = { 'foo' => { 'bar' => [1, 2, 3] } }
response.extend(DeepFetch)

p response.deep_fetch('cars')  { nil } # nil
p response.deep_fetch('cars', 0)  { nil } # nil
p response.deep_fetch('foo')  { nil } # {"bar"=>[1, 2, 3]}
p response.deep_fetch('foo', 'bar', 0)  { nil } # 1
p response.deep_fetch('foo', 'bar', 3)  { nil } # nil
p response.deep_fetch('foo', 'bar', 0, 'engine')  { nil } # nil
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can live with getting an empty hash instead of `nil` when there is no key, then you can do it like this:

```
response.fetch('cars', {}).fetch(0, {}).fetch('engine', {}).fetch('5L', {})
```

or save some types by defining a method `Hash#_`:

```
class Hash; def _ k; fetch(k, {}) end end
response._('cars')._(0)._('engine')._('5L')
```

or do it at once like this:

```
["cars", 0, "engine", "5L"].inject(response){|h, k| h.fetch(k, {})}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of reference, there are several projects i know of that tackle the more general problem of chaining methods in the face of possible `nils`:

- [andand](https://github.com/raganwald/andand)
- [ick](http://ick.rubyforge.org/)
- zucker's [egonil](http://rubyzucker.info/#egonil)
- [methodchain](http://projects.gregweber.info/methodchain)
- *probably others...*

There's also been considerable discussion in the past:

- [Ruby nil-like object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8766191/2004045) - One of many on SO
- [Null Objects and Falsiness](http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/05/30/null-objects-and-falsiness/) - Great article by Avdi Grimm
- [The 28 Bytes of Ruby Joy!](http://rbjl.net/26-the-28-bytes-of-ruby-joy) - Very interesting discussion following J-_-L's post
- [More idiomatic way to avoid errors when calling method on variable that may be nil?](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/218373) on ruby-talk
- *et cetera*

Having said that, the answers already provided probably suffice for the more specific problem of chained `Hash#[]` access.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest an approach of injecting custom `#[]` method to instances we are interested in:

```
def weaken_checks_for_brackets_accessor inst
  inst.instance_variable_set(:@original_get_element_method, inst.method(:[])) \
    unless inst.instance_variable_get(:@original_get_element_method)

  singleton_class = class << inst; self; end
  singleton_class.send(:define_method, :[]) do |*keys|
    begin
      res = (inst.instance_variable_get(:@original_get_element_method).call *keys)
    rescue
    end
    weaken_checks_for_brackets_accessor(res.nil? ? inst.class.new : res)
  end
  inst
end
```

Being called on the instance of Hash (Array is OK as all the other classes, having `#[]` defined), this method stores the original `Hash#[]` method unless it is already substituted (that’s needed to prevent stack overflow during multiple calls.) Then it injects the custom implementation of `#[]` method, returning empty class instance instead of nil/exception. To use the safe value retrieval:

```
a = { 'foo' => { 'bar' => [1, 2, 3] } }

p (weaken_checks_for_brackets_accessor a)['foo']['bar']
p "1 #{a['foo']}"
p "2 #{a['foo']['bar']}"
p "3 #{a['foo']['bar']['ghgh']}"
p "4 #{a['foo']['bar']['ghgh'][0]}"
p "5 #{a['foo']['bar']['ghgh'][0]['olala']}"
```

Yielding:

```
#⇒ [1, 2, 3]
#⇒ "1 {\"bar\"=>[1, 2, 3]}"
#⇒ "2 [1, 2, 3]"
#⇒ "3 []"
#⇒ "4 []"
#⇒ "5 []"
```